# Remove absolute path while uploading file on S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to upload file on S3 in my bucket, using following code which is working absolutely fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import boto
import boto.s3.connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from datetime import datetime
try:


    conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id = 'AKXXXXXXXXXXXXA',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2',
    calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
    )

    print conn
    filename = '/home/rahul/GitDjangopostgres/AWSNewView/company/ExtraPaymentDocuments/Argus_ATM_e_surveillance/Gujarat/Ahmedabad/P3DCAM04/cecb834f-ae85-49e3-b8a1-a6nC^U)3GcZ)M62d643aa7-d047-498c-bf59-8__Invoice (7).pdf'

    bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucketName', validate=False)
    key_name = filename
    print "file to upload",key_name

    secure_https_url = 'https://{host}/{bucket}{key}'.format(
    host=conn.server_name(),
    bucket='bucketName',
    key=key_name)

    print "secure_https_url",secure_https_url

    k = bucket.new_key(key_name)
    mp = k.set_contents_from_filename(key_name)

    print "File uploaded successfully"
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
    print "error"
```

Now the problem is as my file name is `'/home/rahul/GitDjangopostgres/AWSNewView/company/ExtraPaymentDocuments/Argus_ATM_e_surveillance/Gujarat/Ahmedabad/P3DCAM04/cecb834f-ae85-49e3-b8a1-a6nC^U)3GcZ)M62d643aa7-d047-498c-bf59-8__Invoice (7).pdf'`, It's creating hierarchical bucket and storing my file. so I am getting file path as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/home/rahul/GitDjangopostgres/AWSNewView/company/ExtraPaymentDocuments/Argus_ATM_e_surveillance/Gujarat/Ahmedabad/P3DCAM04/cecb834f-ae85-49e3-b8a1-a6nC^U)3GcZ)M62d643aa7-d047-498c-bf59-8__Invoice (7).pdf`.I want to change this hierarchy to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/ExtraPaymentDocuments/Argus_ATM_e_surveillance/Gujarat/Ahmedabad/P3DCAM04/cecb834f-ae85-49e3-b8a1-a6nC^U)3GcZ)M62d643aa7-d047-498c-bf59-8__Invoice (7).pdf`. Is there any option to do it with boto OR should I go with python, because to upload file on s3 it requires absolute path of the file, As I am using `Django` and this is my `celery` task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `set_contents_from_filename(key_name)` understand that whatever is key name it will put it in s3 as it is. If your key name contains any `/` then it will create hierarchy structure. For your situation i suggest that you create two paths. One is your base local path which contains your files. Base local path will contain all your files that you want to upload to s3 (use `os.path.join` for creating the path) Then next is aws path which is the hierarchy you want to create in your s3 bucket. As an example you can declare the aws path as:

```
/ExtraPaymentDocuments/Argus_ATM_e_surveillance/Gujarat/Ahmedabad/P3DCAM04
```

Then you append the local filename to the parameter key_name which you will pass to function `new_key`.
 Boto will work fine here.

example:
create a s3 path that you want in your s3 storage and also add a base local path which contain all the files that you want to upload. filename has to be appended to create a file. `new_key` function will create a key i.e. path that you can use to store your files. `set_contents_from_filename` function will take a local file path and store this file to s3 with the key (path) provided in the function above.

```
k = bucket.new_key(s3_path + filename)
mp = k.set_contents_from_filename(base_local_path _ filename)
```

Comment: You mean to say `k = bucket.new_key(key_name1)
    mp = k.set_contents_from_filename(key_name2)` I can put key_name1 and key_name2 different?

Comment: see the final edit. It should work for you perfectly.